# Add Condition in CURL - Refreshed Token

Tags: php, curl

I would like to set a condition on a CURL function to check and replace expired token with refreshed token.

Below are the codes below to retrieve and store a token. I am using file_put_contents currently.

```
function getToken() {
$ch = curl_init();

$url = $this->config['URL'];
$id = $this->config['ID'];
$secret = $this->config['SECRET'];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"client_id\": \"$id\",
  \"client_secret\": \"$secret\",
  \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response, true);
$file = 'key.txt';
$token = $json['access_token'];

file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/key.txt', $token, LOCK_EX);
}
```

The token stored is used in CURL execution. I would like to implement a condition in which I have to check and replace the stated token if it has expired. That said, the CURL execution will loop and retrieve a refreshed token and store in key.txt.

response.txt and results.txt are files used for troubleshooting.

Below are my codes:

```
$file = './modules/custommodule/key.txt';
$retrieved_token = file_get_contents($file);

//curl execution here

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer $retrieved_token"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//conditional statement here

curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/response.txt', $response, LOCK_EX);
file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/results.txt', $httpcode, LOCK_EX);
```

I have tested without any conditional statement with an expired token. It is returning successfully response http error 401 and code:2011. I am looking into using these values to set the condition.

I am in need of assistance to guide me on how to set the condition (probably with if/else statement with while loop) to get the execution right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check it working to refresh token curl

```
 curl -i --user 'gigy:secret' \
    -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=gigy&client_secret=secret&refresh_token=5ce4902a-e466-452d-8bbb-0fb1bf378f8a' \
    -X POST http://localhost:8000/gigy/oauth/token
```

Comment: Hello @pardeep, I am currently storing the token in key.txt. I would like to set the condition with $httpcode probably? Since it returns status for me to use. I am unsure on how I could set a if/else condition to check on expired token and replace it with a new one.